# crystal report doesn't show up on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm not a professional programmer, just a student who wants to learn more on how to figure out what's wrong with my codes. I can't make my crystal report appear from my asp.net, I'm having a database error. I tried changing the server still it doesn't work :'(

here is my first code:

```
ataAdapterpublic partial class Reports_Publisher : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon());
---------------------------------------------------------------
    report.SetParameterValue("User", "--");
    crvpublisher.ReportSource = report;
    crvpublisher.DataBind();
    con.Close();
   }
}
```

here is my second code:

```
public partial class Reports_Publisher : System.Web.UI.Page
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon());
```

---

```
    report.SetParameterValue("User", Helper.GetData("userFN") + " " + 
    Helper.GetData("userLN"));

    crvpublisher.ReportSource = report;
    crvpublisher.DataBind();
    con.Close();
   }

}
```

I still get the database error on my asp.net :<
I did have my back up in my sql and it's working properly together with the server. what am I doing wrong? what should I do?

Comment: I removed the database login details you left in your code. Posting that stuff on a public website isn't a very good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your SQL connection String is to blame. I'm not sure what the Helper.GetCon() is supposed to accomplish, but traditionally a connection string looks more like this:

```
SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(local)\sqlexpress;Integrated  
Security=True;" + "Database=DB");
```

Check out this site [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/) for some more examples.

Hope that helps,

Chris